# Fill in Android SeekBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-seekbar

I am trying to make an hourglass android SeekBar. When I try to get it to completely fill in the SeekBar, it only fills in the center. How can I make the Vertical SeekBar's slider wider?

What it looks like currently:

[image]

What I want it to look like:

[image]

Please note that the INSIDE of the hourglass is transparent and the OUTSIDE is grey. I've been trying to find a way to have the image placed over the SeekBar so it will fill it in. The first image is what it looks like with the image as a background for the SeekBar.

Comment: How do you get that shape ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan It was a drawable resource.

Comment: could you post it? maybe I can give it a try

Comment: All that needed to happen was the `ProgressBar` needed to be thicker in width (it was a vertical progress bar). For some reason, it would not get thicker. See my answer for how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting to do this, you can't. I ended up making 25 images for the progress bar's 25 states. These images were updated in an `ImageView` behind the progress bar. I made the `ProgressBar` transparent so it would not show up over the image. When the progress changed, I updated the image.